# Video Processing - Offline vs Online

Tags: video-streaming, video-processing, video-encoding

I'm building a social media app similar to TikTok.
Currently, I'm giving the user possibility to add music, combine videos. In the future, I would like to give the possibility to add filters, etc.

I built a concept on iOS and the whole video processing is done on phone, afterward encoded video is being uploaded to the server.
Currently, I've started working on the Android version. However, because of fragmentation, encoding on Android is pain.

I'm considering changing my strategy, send raw video files to the server, and then do video processing/encoding.

Have you ever worked on apps like that or do you know how e.g. TikTok solves it?

Answer (score 0):

The main problem with video processing and manipulation on a mobile device is the processing power, and related battery power, often required.

If your user experience works well with the video processing being done on the server side this sounds like a good plan.

If you do want to do video processing on the device then staying as 'native' as possible will help - i.e. use the standard codecs and Media API's etc on the device as these will likely be HW accelerated.

- https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/package-summary

If these don't meet your requirements then FFMPEG may provide what you want but you may find it is slower - one of the easiest way to use FFMPEG on Android is via a wrapper project - e.g.:

- https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android-java

This library has an example app you can test with first which may allow you check if the performance meets your needs.